# Prevent font color from changing when hovering over child menu item

Tags: css, css3

I'm baffling myself with this one.

I have a main menu set up and when you hover over a menu item the background-color is #f2dabd and the color is #8d0000, however when i hover over a parent menu item, the dropdown appears as expected, but if i then hover over a child item the parent menu title font colour changes (the parent item is neither :active or :hover but the hover background color still applies. I cannot seem to figure out how to prevent it from doing this.

Its a little hard to explain so I will provide a link to the development site in question:

Ok so if you hover over the menu item Services then without clicking, hover over one of the child items such as Restoration, you will see that the 'Services' text changes colour to match the hover background color. I just can't seem to figure out how to target it with css?

Any advise would be most appreciated. I had asked this in the Joomla specific exchange, and received an answer - but the answer no longer seems to work, thus as it isnt Joomla specific, I am asking this here.

Regards D

Comment: The colour gets set by `#menu ul > li span.zen-menu-heading:hover{color: #666}`. When you are no longer hovering over that element the hover no longer applies, so it falls back on the `#menu ul > li span.zen-menu-heading` colour rule, which is now the same colour as the background.

Comment: Thanks @TimFountain - This is what the problem is - I need to maintain the hover color on the parent item when hovering on the child item - Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. It its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The over the `li` is what causing the problem.

So when you hover over the `span` the `color` changes but when you hover over the `li` only the `background-color` changes .

To resolve the problem you need to change the `color` of the `span` when you hover over the `li`.

```
.zen-menu-horizontal ul li:hover > span {
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) All sorted. I couldn't see the wood for the tree's.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)